# mongodb HTTPS endpoint delete by _id

Tags: https, mongodb-query, endpoint

Able to post and get using HTTPS endpoints but having trouble with deleteOne.  Any suggestions?

```
axios.delete(
    'https://<my db url>/endpoint/DeleteExercise', {
        params: { "_id": ObjectId(editedExerciseId)},
     })
```

Also tried data instead of params.  My endpoint function is:

```
exports = function({ query, headers, body}, response) {
const docs = context.services
.get("mongodb-atlas")
.db("gymlog")
.collection("exercises")
.deleteOne({});

return;

};
```

get back:  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
ReferenceError: Property 'ObjectId' doesn't exist

Comment: Why has your question to do with https? Does it work without https? Because otherwise it is just the used protection that has. Nothing tk do with your question.